# Remove duplicate string key in a text using command line

Tags: regex, command-line, duplicates, unique

I was trying to remove some duplicate string in a line by line text. eg:

```
A {id: "x" p {id: "vcv" v: "i4"} on:taf"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "wse" v: "i4"} on:ue"}
A {id: "z" p {id: "das" v: "i4"} on:tade"}
A {id: "x" p {id: "da" v: "i4"} on:faer"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "werw" v: "i4"} on:asee"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "werw" v: "i4"} on:asee"}
```

the output should be the ones with no duplicated A_id, which means the output should be:

```
A {id: "x" p {id: "vcv" v: "i4"} on:taf"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "wse" v: "i4"} on:ue"}
A {id: "z" p {id: "das" v: "i4"} on:tade"}
```

The problem I met was I don't know how to sort and make it unique with a substring only.
I tried to use:

```
cat input.txt | grep 'A\s\{id:\s\"[^;]*\sp\s\{id:' | sort -u > output.txt
```

But it doesn't remove the duplicate substring but only remove lines which are exactly the same with others. So it's like it only removed:

```
A {id: "y" p {id: "werw" v: "i4"} on:asee"}
```

which is all the same with the last two lines, but didn't remove:

```
A {id: "y" p {id: "wse" v: "i4"} on:ue"}
```

which has the duplicate id but different content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An awk solution:

```
$ awk '!a[$3]++' file
A {id: "x" p {id: "vcv" v: "i4"} on:taf"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "wse" v: "i4"} on:ue"}
A {id: "z" p {id: "das" v: "i4"} on:tade"}
```

Combing the matching from your grep command:

```
$ awk '$1=="A" && $2=="{id:" && $4=="p" && $5=="{id:" && !a[$3]++' file
A {id: "x" p {id: "vcv" v: "i4"} on:taf"}
A {id: "y" p {id: "wse" v: "i4"} on:ue"}
A {id: "z" p {id: "das" v: "i4"} on:tade"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sort` uses the entire string as key by default, so it would only eliminate identical lines.

Try changing

```
sort -u
```

to

```
sort -uk3,3
```

to eliminate duplicates where the key is the 3rd field. Fields are separated by white-space.

> -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>         start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
>
> POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number    and  C  the 
>   character    position  in  the  field.   OPTS  is one or more
>   single-letter ordering    options, which override global ordering
>   options for that   key.   If  no    key is given, use the entire line as
>   the key.

[Reference](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort).

Comment: I used command like this :cat ~/lexicon.clex | sort -u -k 1 20 > ~/output.clex, but it said "sort: open failed: 20: No such file or directory"

Comment: @QingshanZhang I think it was a syntax error from my side, try adding a comma between `1` and `10`, see edit.

Comment: @Dukeling the syntax error was caused from the missing comma, this doesn't do what the OP needs.

Comment: ye that works now but didn't remove duplicate substring, the one with awk works! But thank you so much for the help anyway! don't know who down-vote this but I vote it to balance it.:)

Comment: @sudo_O I don't see the problem (not that I have a Linux machine to test this on), except that maybe the result of `grep` includes results in a format other than those listed (which I suppose is quite possible from that regex).

Comment: The problem is `-k1,10` means the first 10 columns. The OP wants to filter unique value in the third column which would be `sort -uk3,3 file`. You should **always** test your answers (use ideone.com if you don't have a Linux machine to test on) @QingshanZhang do not upvote to counter balance a downvote, this answer is wrong.

Comment: @sudo_O You learn something new every day. I was convinced `sort` uses characters not white-space separated fields. Anyway, edited.

Comment: You should have read the reference you linked to, specifically the part I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\{id: "([^"]+)"/ and not exists $h{$1}) { $h{$1}++; print }'
```

It stores the ids that matched in a hash, and only prints if the id was not already in the hash.

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with perl as well, but thank you for the help:)